Removing unused master slides of a Power Point using Office Add-in
I want to remove unused master slides using Office 365 Add-ins(preferred, if not feasible then C# code).
I want this similar solution. The requirement is to reduce the size of the PowerPoint by removing the unnecessary or unused master slides. Please suggest or guide how can I achieve the same.
I wish to achieve this by using Office Add-in (Javascript or Typescript), if it is not possible then I can go with with C#(using Visual Studio)
